# как уравнять массивы в php

Tags: php

Добрый день. Прошу помощи друзья! есть 2 массива array1, array2. любой может быть длиннее другого. как их уравнять добавляя в конец короткого массива например 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
$secondArray = [1,2];

$countFirstArray = count($firstArray);
$countSecondArray = count($secondArray);

if ($countSecondArray!=$countFirstArray) {
    if ($countFirstArray<$countSecondArray) {
        $smallArray = &$firstArray;
    } else {
        $smallArray = &$secondArray;
    }

    $smallArray = array_pad($smallArray, max($countFirstArray, $countSecondArray), 0);
}
```

[Официальная документация по функции array_pad](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-pad.php)

Comment: И вам спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

[array_pad](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-pad.php)

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
$b = [1];

$w = max(count($a), count($b));

$a = array_pad($a, $w, 0);
$b = array_pad($b, $w, 0);

var_dump($a, $b);
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/fLJKc)

Comment: Благодарю. Узнал кое-что новое не зря прожил день))